# Open shared folder with different credentials in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Iam using vbscripr to open network folder like

```
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.Open "\\xxxxxxxxxxx\c$"
```

I don't have access for the drive "yyyy" but i have the UN and PW. how can i use the credentials in vbscript to open the shared folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you cannot do this. The "open" method does not allow you to pass a parameter other than the directory name and the "Shell.Application" object doesn't have a method to do it either.

Source:

Open Method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774086(v=vs.85).aspx

List of Methods for Shell.Application:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094(v=vs.85).aspx

A possible workaround to this issue would be to relaunch your script via the command prompt and call something like PSEXEC. Something like this:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "%COMSPEC% /C psexec -u domain\user -p password -accepteula cscript.exe c:\path\yourscript.vbs"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

You can download PSEXEC from here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Answer (score -1):

As awful as it is I use sendkeys (after a little wscript.sleep 2000)...

```
`...
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strShare) 'check access
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    WScript.Sleep 2000
    objShell.SendKeys "username" 'username
    objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    objShell.SendKeys "password" 'password
    objShell.SendKeys "{Tab}" 
    objShell.SendKeys " " 'save credentials
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{Tab}" 
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
End If
Set ObjShell = Nothing
...`
```